# ViewModel observes LiveData from another ViewModel

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have an `Activity`, that contains some views and 2 Fragments (for example, `TextInputFragment` and `VoiceInputFragment`).

I created the next ViewModels:

- `ActivityViewModel` with `void onInput(String value)` method
- `interface InputViewModel` with `LiveData<String> getInput()` method
- `TextInputViewModel` and `VoiceInputViewModel` as implementation of `InputViewModel`

Now I want to observe getInput from both fragments and react on them.
I have the next idea:

`Activity.onCreate`:

```
ActivityViewModel avm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ActivityViewModel.class);

TextInputViewModel tivm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TextInputViewModel.class);
tivm.getInput().observeForever(avm::onInput);

VoiceInputViewModel vivm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(VoiceInputViewModel.class);
vivm.getInput().observeForever(avm::onInput);
```

Does this idea correct? What happened when configuration change and my ViewModels try to re-observe each other? Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

After reseaching and reading `android.arch` sources I came to the next solution:

Change type of `ActivityViewModel.answer` field to `MediatorLiveData<String>` and add the next method:

```
public void addAnswerSource(LiveData<String> source) {
    answer.removeSource(source); // to prevent throwing "This source was already added with the different observer" exception
    answer.addSource(source, s -> answer.setValue(s));
}
```

Now `Activity.onCreate`:

```
ActivityViewModel avm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ActivityViewModel.class);

TextInputViewModel tivm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TextInputViewModel.class);
avm.addAnswerSource(tivm.getInput());

VoiceInputViewModel vivm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(VoiceInputViewModel.class);
avm.addAnswerSource(vivm.getInput());
```